# Using AutoCompleteTextView with RecyclerView

Tags: android

When I try to use AutoCompleteTextView with RecyclerView I getting this exception while testing.

Note: Popup shows in AutoCompleteTextView, but when I move continuously to the upcoming textview's and try to add text rarely this exception occurs.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.app.test, PID: 10445
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.setFitsSystemWindows(boolean)' on a null object reference
   at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1254)
   at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1110)
   at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:658)
   at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1106)
   at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:975)
   at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:957)
   at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

Don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Post your `Activity` too.Probably you have forgot to add `findViewById`

Comment: @meditat.. Its working... In rare scenario only I am getting this exception. Still if you want code I will post.

Comment: @Gunaseelan Did you find out what causing it?